# Append a variable from within an AJAX success call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I successfully use this variable within the the appended message of the AJAX success call?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/fdBvn

```
data['name'] = $('#goofy').val();

$.ajax({
 url: '/api/1/email/test/',
 data: data,
 type: 'POST',
 error: function(){
 alert("Sorry, error with our server, we're working on it now");
},
success: function(){
$('#success').append('<h2>Thanks "+data['name']+"!</h2><p>We will be in touch shortly</p>');
}
});
```

Comment: The coloring coding in the post shows you what is wrong....

Comment: [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners) and you will be able to solve such issues yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use proper quoting.

```
$('#success')
  .append('<h2>Thanks '+data['name']+'!</h2><p>We will be in touch shortly</p>');
```

Notice that in your code you're opening your string with `'` but closing it with `"`